# PHP echo all values in an inner-most array from a stdClass object

Tags: php

How can I get(echo/print) all of the username values from a variable which is a stdClass object? below is the structure of this variable I got from var_dump. thanks!

```
object(stdClass)[4]
public 'rows' => 
array (size=7)
      0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'username' => string 'Justin' (length=6)
      'password' => string '123' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'username' => string 'Papino' (length=6)
      'password' => string '456' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'username' => string 'Sophia' (length=6)
      'password' => string '789' (length=3)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'username' => string 'something' (length=3)
      'password' => string '1234' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet change `$object` with your StdClass Object Name.

```
$userNames = [];
foreach($object->rows as $item){
  $userNames []  = $item['username'];
}

var_dump($userNames);
```

**update after comments**
There is no way to do it with `var_dump` solely, you should some jobs to get it.

in my projects I always use [Krumo](https://github.com/mmucklo/krumo) instead of `print_r` , `var_dump`

```
$userNames = [];
foreach($object->rows as $item){
  echo  $item['username'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but I don't want to var_dump the $userNames, I already have those values saved in my variable like $result for example. If I var_dump my $result I got above data structure which is a stdClass includes a 2 dimensional array, all I want is echo/print out all of the inner-most values like Justin,Papino,Sophia...NOT var_dump again!!!! hope I explained this well.

Comment: he answer is missing a ' in `$item['username];` but if you just need to echo them out, the replace that line with `echo $item['username'].PHP_EOL;` or something similar.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for your comment, I updated missing '.

Comment: This answer will basically work, just change this line `$userNames []  = $item['username'];` to `echo $item['username']."<br>\n";` and then delete the var_dump line.

Comment: Thanks, I simply used
foreach($result->rows as $item){
  echo $item['username'];
}
which did the perfect job.

Comment: @Huyimin not very diffs but I added it you my answer,;)

Answer (score 1):

Use array_map in order to get an array of usernames like so:

```
array_map(function($row) {
    echo $row['username'];
}, $object->rows);

// $usernames = ['Papino', 'Sophia', ..]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work, PHP reports Parse error for unexpected ')', however this is not I am cared about.
I think there must a way to echo the values that held in my $result variable which is a stdClass object as I mentioned above, by using the  foreach or while loop, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: I put an extra ) my answer is updated, if you only want to print the usernames change the return for echo